# Multiple database connection with same table manes laravel

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel-5

I have two database having tables with same name. 
I am using laravel to connect through this.

Note : I am able to make multiple connections but I am unable to access tables having same name.

Example

Database 1 :

Table: ads

Database 2

Table: ads

How can I make database connection / model for these two different tables having same name , which are in two different databases.

Comment: Inside your Model add this property:  
`protected $connection = 'connection-name';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer your tables with db names... for example db1.ads & db2.ads ... hope it helps

Comment: Yes working fine like this.thanks.

Comment: cool.. can you mark it as correct answer ,,